# Getting 404 error for my MVC url in retrofit post method

Tags: android

I am calling post method of retrofit for my forgot password screen but i am getting null response and reason is 404 url not found error please guide me over it I a beginner in retrofit.

my **main url** is this:

```
http://10.25.1.180:98/webapi/ForgtPassword

I am setting url like this
```

**Base url Declaration** :

```
public static String BASE_URL = "http://10.25.1.180:98/";
```

**interface** :

```
public interface APIService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/webapi/ForgtPassword")
    Call<LoginModel> updateUser(@Field("username") String first, @Field("Device") String device);
}
```

**Mainactivity.java** :

```
TextView responseText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        responseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
        APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);




        /**
         Create new user
         **/

        LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel("viren.r","A");
        Call<LoginModel> call1 = apiInterface.createUser(loginModel);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
                LoginModel user1 = response.body();
                Log.e("Response is====",response.toString());

                if (response.isSuccessful())
                    Log.e("Success", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                else

                    Log.e("unSuccess", new Gson().toJson(response.errorBody()));


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail=====", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }


        });

        /**
         GET List Users
         **/
//        Call<UserList> call2 = apiInterface.doGetUserList("2");
//        call2.enqueue(new Callback<UserList>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {
//
//                UserList userList = response.body();
//                Integer text = userList.page;
//                Integer total = userList.total;
//                Integer totalPages = userList.totalPages;
//                List<UserList.Datum> datumList = userList.data;
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text + " page\n" + total + " total\n" + totalPages + " totalPages\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//                for (UserList.Datum datum : datumList) {
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id : " + datum.id + " name: " + datum.first_name + " " + datum.last_name + " avatar: " + datum.avatar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onFailure(Call<UserList> call, Throwable t) {
//                call.cancel();
//            }
//        });


        /**
         POST name and job Url encoded.
         **/
//        Call<UserList> call3 = apiInterface.doCreateUserWithField("morpheus","leader");
//        call3.enqueue(new Callback<UserList>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {
//                UserList userList = response.body();
//                Integer text = userList.page;
//                Integer total = userList.total;
//                Integer totalPages = userList.totalPages;
//                List<UserList.Datum> datumList = userList.data;
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text + " page\n" + total + " total\n" + totalPages + " totalPages\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//                for (UserList.Datum datum : datumList) {
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id : " + datum.id + " name: " + datum.first_name + " " + datum.last_name + " avatar: " + datum.avatar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onFailure(Call<UserList> call, Throwable t) {
//                call.cancel();
//            }
//        });

    }
}
```

I am calling retrofit library from main activity using Apiclient class

```
public class APIClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();



        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

how I resolve this error. please give me guidence to set url is any extension required to set mvc url like php.In php url ending with .php extension anything required like this in mvc?

Why I am getting this error for webapi url?Is anything missing in my code.

Comment: are you sure that the url is accessible from your device?

Comment: Try hitting the url in the browser or Postman to first make sure that the url is working.

Comment: Try to remove forward slash "/" at the end of `BASE_URL`.

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: issue is resolved but now my problem is that response is this how i parse this response {"Response":[{"result":"0","Email":"ws.dev@wealthstreet.in"}]}

Comment: what you want to do with response now ? if you want to set to Somewhere or show user toast then use this : abc.setText(response.body!!.Email) Or for Toast : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body!!.email , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();